# How to convert data from firebase to an html array

Tags: html, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

i want to replace this data(html array) with the retrieve data from my firebase database.

```
    var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
```

here is how database looks like

[I want to put parkers on the location and set the other attributes as descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ6nL.png)

can someone help me how to turn my data from firebase to an html array like the code above.

why using .on rather than .once does not update the table when updating the database.

```
    rootRef.on("child_added", snap =>{
    var date = snap.child("dateAndTime").val();
    var lat = snap.child("latitude").val();
    var long = snap.child("longitude").val();
    var link = snap.child("link").val();
    var report = snap.child("report").val();
    var status = snap.child("status").val();
    var needs = snap.child("needs").val();


    $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" +date+"</td><td>"+report+"</td><td>"+lat+"</td><td>"+long+"</td><td>"+status+"</td><td>"+needs+"</tr>");

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add google map marker from firebase database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216708/how-to-add-google-map-marker-from-firebase-database)

Comment: that's for android. My question is about web.

Comment: really? You have remove all the code written. Why ?

Comment: i've figured out already what to do with the rest of the code. the only problem now was the conversion of the data into an html array like the one above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching from firebase

I assume firebase is setup with correct settings

```
// Default markers
var locations = [{
    report: "Bondi Beach",
    longitude: -33.890542,
    latitude: 151.274856
}, {
    report: "Maroubra Beach",
    longitude: -33.950598,
    latitude: 151.274856
}];

 var colors = [
   "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png",
   "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png"
 ]


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markers = []

// To dynamically change marker color, use marker[i].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')

function renderMarkers() {

    // Clearout old markers
    markers.map(function (oldMarker) {
        oldMarker.setMap(null)
    })
    markers = []

    locations.map(function (loc) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc.longitude, loc.latitude),
            map: map,
            icon: loc.completed ? colors[0] : colors[1]
        });
        markers.push(marker)
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(loc.report);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, loc));
    })
}
renderMarkers()


firebase.database.ref('/database/5-11-2017').on('value', function (snapshot) {
    var result = snapshot.val()

    if (!result) return

    // I dont know you database, either it will return objects or array.
    locations = Object.keys(result).map(function (key) {
        return result[key]
    })
    // or
    // locations = result // Array

    // Render makers with new locations
    renderMarkers()

})
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/priyesh9875/18mjagyu/1/)
To simulate loading of data, I have added timeout function. Map should render new markers after about 5 seconds.

Comment: Kumar, my database was the link with the description "i want to put markers . . .". actually i just want to retrieve the data from the database to an html array like the one above

Comment: @Est so its not doing ? Above code should do the job. It not, you must read the docs

Comment: Thanks man, i made i work. thanks for your help. can i ask you another question? is it possible to use marker with different color? for example in my database, there's an ongoing events and those that were already done. can i place markers that will show different color from one another? example. red for ongoing and green for done

Comment: @ Priyesh  thanks man, is it possible to refresh markers for a certain time? like every 1 minute? because i'm getting the location from real - time database and i want to update all markers regarding their status(No response yet, ongoing, done). TIA

Comment: Firebase has a realtime database. So whenever data changes, above function will be called automatically, no need to poll. All you need to update the database

Comment: yeah, that's what i thought. but when i tried it, i need to reload the page to get the update from firebase. Can we set a timer for example. every 5 minutes the page will reload?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that `once` will not refresh the data. Change it to `on`.  See updated code. You can refresh page every 5 min, but that will be painful from user point

Comment: thanks.but why when i used `on` instead of `once` in this code. It does not update my table everytime i update my database. ill update my question